# JavaScript get common element in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array which is `eewootags`:

[image]

and I have another array `evProductTag` which is below:

[image]

I am trying to get the id which is common to both.

This is what I tried:

```
var tagdataexist = [];
for (var i = 0; i < evProductTag.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < eewootags.length; j++) {
    if (eewootags[j].name == evProductTag[i].name){
      tagdataexist.push(eewootags[i].id);
    }
  }
}
console.log(tagdataexist);
```

But this gives be `193` instead of `187`.
`Tag2` is the common element by name.

Please help!

Comment: Please show all data as text, not as pictures of text. Note that getting data from JavaScript is often easier using `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` to get a string value you can then copy and paste. Please try to limit the amount of data to only enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the indexes of your array: you access `eewootags` with both `i` and `j`. You need to use always the same index!

```js
let eewootags = [
  {id: 193, name: 'Tag 8'},
  {id: 186, name: 'Tag1'},
  {id: 187, name: 'Tag2'},
  {id: 188, name: 'Tag3'},
  {id: 189, name: 'Tag4'},
  {id: 190, name: 'Tag5'},
  {id: 191, name: 'Tag6'},
  {id: 192, name: 'Tag7'},
  {id: 194, name: 'Tag9'}
];
let evProductTag = [
  {name: 'Tag2'},
  {name: 'Tag 3'},
  {name: 'Tag 69'}
];
let tagdataexist = [];
for (let i = 0; i < eewootags.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < evProductTag.length; j++) {
    if (eewootags[i].name == evProductTag[j].name) {
      tagdataexist.push(eewootags[i].id);
    }
  }
}
console.log(tagdataexist);
```

Answer (score 1):

your error is just on index!

```
tagdataexist.push(eewootags[j].id);// j and not i
```